# Is there any feature available to access a aggregate count function in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm new to Node.js and Mongoose library. My problem is i have two collections schema

1. Restaurant
2. Reviews

I tried to add a virtual field (`reviews_count`) in `Restaurent` collection for reviews count.

How can I achieve this one? Is there any specific function available in mongoose?

```
    Restaurant:                      Reviews:

    _id: ObjectId                   restaurent_id: (Restaurant ref id)
    name: String                    review: String
```

I expect the output while try to get the restaurant details.

```
{
  "_id": "2344....",
  "name": "Restaurant name".
  "reviews_count": 220
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, this is possible. There are many ways to do it: You could actually define an async virtual, that will query Reviews, but I don't like this approach too much, since you have to make sure to await it or to handle a callback, which looks and smells bad:

`const count = await restaurant.reviews`

Alternatively, you could just define an [instance method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods) something like this (async would be better, tough), which I like better, since it makes the code easier to read, when calling this function:

```
  // assign a function to the "methods" object of your restaurant schema
  restaurant.methods.getReviews = function(cb) {
    return this.model('Reviews').find({ restaurant_id: this._id }, cb);
  };
```

Finally, there is a third, and in my opinion the best option: **Virtual Populate**
Mongoose 4.5 introduced this feature and it perfectly fits your usecase. Define your field like this:

```
Restaurant.virtual('reviews', {
  ref: 'Reviews',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'restaurant_id'
});
```

and then query it like this:

```
Restaurant.findOne().populate('reviews').exec(function(error, reviews) {
  // `reviews.count` is the virtual you are looking for
});
```

This is imho the cleanest and most versatile solution since it keeps you from unnecessarily adding arrays with refs to you your main object and still get an easy access to all reviews of a restaurant. You can find a good article here:
http://thecodebarbarian.com/mongoose-virtual-populate

Note: This solution might give you performance problems, since we always query the whole review document and not just the count. If you feel like this might be a problem, you might want to first add the .lean() function to your query, and if that doesn't help much, you can resort to one of the first two approaches I outlined.